# Help with database schema

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a project and I would need help with proper design a database schema. This is the application where users can add appliances in their home. For example, television, washing machine, dishwasher line, fridge, freezer. Each one of these appliances have different parameters that I need to store in a database. I do not think they are effective represent each category of appliances separately, but on the other hand, I do not know how to include them in a single table.

I only have five categories, so five tables it was not a problem, but if they got a hundred, so I do not come quite inefficient. Do you have someone experience something similar or know to help me in my case?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: You would want to determine what was common about the categories, such as manufacturer, model, serial number and store the rest as JSON or XML.  Querying inside of JSON or XML will be slower (depends on your specified RDBMS) but storing the most often queries items in the table should keep things pretty efficient.

Comment: There is a tag, [Tag:subtypes] that deals with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with a more general structure, such as this:

```
appliances
----------
  id (PK)
  name (such as "bedroom TV", "main freezer", etc...)


parameter_types
---------------
  id (PK)
  type (such as "STRING", "INT", ...) - You might only be to enforce this in the application code, rather than in the database.


appliance_parameter
-------------------
  id (PK)
  name (such as "Model name", "Max. operating temperature", "IP address", etc...)
  parameter_type_id (FK to parameter_types.id)

appliance_parameter_values
--------------------------
  id
  appliance_id (FK to appliances.id)
  appliance_parameter_id (FK to appliance_parameters.id)
  value
```

This could be populated as:

```
appliances
ID  | name
----+------------
1   | Marcel's TV
2   | Main fridge
3   | coffee maker

parameter_types
ID  | type
----+---------
1   | STRING
2   | NUMERIC

appliance_parameter
ID  | name        | parameter_type_id
----+-------------+------------------
1   | model number| 1
2   | colour      | 1
3   | IP addr     | 1
4   | weight (kg) | 2

appliance_parameter_values
ID  | appliance_id  | appliance_parameter_id | value
----+---------------+------------------------+-------------
1   | 1             | 1                      | TV-01A
2   | 1             | 2                      | Magenta
3   | 1             | 3                      | 192.0.0.1
4   | 1             | 4                      | 3.2
5   | 3             | 3                      | 192.0.0.2
6   | 3             | 4                      | 1.2
7   | 3             | 2                      | grey
8   | 2             | 1                      | FRDG-001
```

In this example, you don't need to create specific columns for appliances. You create date for an appliance parameter in a specific table, then populate values into `appliance_parameter_values` when you need to. This system can handle any number of appliances with any number of parameters, as long as you can add the appropriate records for them.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a limited number of types of appliances (fridges, washing machines, coffeemakers etc.) from a limited number of manufacturers. Each type must be having its own stable enough set of parameters. If this is correct then you may have the following structure:

- one generic table for all appliances (ApplianceID, ApplianceTypeID, ApplianceModel, ManufacturerID, SerialNumber, PowerIn...),
- a set of type-specific extension tables, each containing type-specific parameters and related to the generic table as one-to-one, and
- a table of types(ApplianceTypeID,ApplianceTypeName, ExtensionTableName).
  Such a structure is less universal than an attribute-value model but easier to query.